# Using org.apache.http.legacy in Android 9

Tags: java, android

I have an old android app that uses the apache legacy Http library (org.apache.http.legacy). After the changes on Android 6, I was able to keep the app working including the legacy library.

**useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy**'.

Now in Android 9 devices I get the below exceptions at runtime.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory' does not implement interface 'org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactory' in call to 'java.net.Socket org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactory.createSocket(org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)' (declaration of 'org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator' appears in /data/app/com.theprojectfactory.wmp-RdZODaT5h-l1diSw3oNCvA==/base.apk)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
```

Reading the [Android 9 changes docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28), there is a mention to add `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>` in the AndroidManifes.xml file, however that does not seem to work for me either as I get the below exception instead when launching the app.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Superclass org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams of org.apache.http.params.SyncBasicHttpParams is declared final (declaration of 'org.apache.http.params.SyncBasicHttpParams' appears in /data/app/com.theprojectfactory.wmp-R2P9RNgoJ82ZupwxVa7iNA==/base.apk)
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
    at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.scanForModelClasses(ModelInfo.java:187)
    at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.scanForModel(ModelInfo.java:152)
    at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.<init>(ModelInfo.java:63)
    at com.activeandroid.Cache.initialize(Cache.java:66)
    at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:44)
    at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:34)
    at com.activeandroid.content.ContentProvider.onCreate(ContentProvider.java:39)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1917)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Any pointers on how to keep using the org.apache.http.legacy on Android 9 api will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after further troubleshooting found out that issue was due to a third party library (activeandroid). Library was using reflection to check all classes available in the classpath and for some reason the legacy apache HTTP classes conflicted when calling **java.lang.Class.classForName**. Skipped the reflection code and app worked as expected. On versions below Android 9 this is not an issue though.

So correct way is as per documentation using: `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>`. If you come across random exceptions check you are not using reflection to try to traverse the legacy HTTP classes.

Comment: Thank you, your solution helped me a lot!

Comment: I use "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6" on Android 9 and your response help me. Nice. But how you understand that problem is in "org.apache.http.legacy"?

Answer (score 11):

You have to add attribute of **android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"** on application tag in  AndroidManifes.xml file.

And also add this.

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kaushal, but this does't work either. Just checked docs and seems usesCleartextTraffic="true" is the default value anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Your classes seem to be conflicting.

> As an alternative to using the runtime Apache library, apps can bundle their own version of the `org.apache.http` library in their APK. If you do this, you must repackage the library (with a utility like [Jar Jar](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar)) to avoid class compatibility issues with the classes provided in the runtime.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p)